# Get edited row data on click

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am new to ReactJS and I've been having some trouble of getting ReactTable  working.

I've defined Cells to be editable like this:

```
const [editing, setEditing] = useState(null);   

const columns = [{
  Header: 'Brand',
  accessor: 'brand',
  Cell: props => editableCell(props)
}]

const editableCell = props => {
 return (editing !== null && editing.index === props.index) ? (<div
  contentEditable="true"
  suppressContentEditableWarning>
   {props.value}
 </div>) : props.value;
}

return (
 <ReactTable
  data={cars} 
  columns={columns} 
  pages={pages}
  loading={loading}
  defaultPageSize={pageSize}
  className="-striped -highlight"/>
);

const edit = row => {
 if(editing !== null && editing.index !== row.index){
  return;
 }
 setEditing(row);
}

const save = () => {
 console.log(editing); // should return edited data, but returns old data, because data doesn't update when user modifies each cell.
}
```

How do I get new data from the edited row upon save? Do I have to create a listener that changes the values to state while typing? I know why it doesn't work, but I don't know what or how to implement.

Comment: Where are you setting your state?

Comment: When user clicks edit button on row. I call setEditing and pass the row as argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your could use `onBlur()` event for `contentEditable` div and inside `onBlur` event you can get value using `e.target.innerHTML` or `e.target.innerText`.

And inside of this `editableCell` function you will get you data using `props.original`. Using this `props.original` you can find your data from the state and after that if you want to update the data into `state` then you can do easily.

Please check below code and working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-edited-row-data-on-click) demo.

```
editableCell(props) {
    return (
      <div
        className={"edittable"}
        contentEditable
        suppressContentEditableWarning
        onBlur={e => {
          console.log(`original value : ${JSON.stringify(props.original)}`)
          const data = [...this.state.data];
          let row = data.find(o=>o.id == props.original.id);
          row[props.column.id] = e.target.innerHTML;
          console.log(`upated row value : ${JSON.stringify(row)}`)
        }}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: this.state.data[props.index][props.column.id]
        }}
      />
    );
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why the code sometimes produces "space" as &nbsp; ? This happens after onBlur. What is the point of "dangerouslySetInnerHTML"?

Comment: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is React’s replacement for using `innerHTML` in the browser DOM. `for this Do you have any idea why the code sometimes produces "space" as &nbsp; ? This happens after onBlur. ` could you share me screenshot

Comment: Is it necessary to use it? I just get by fine without it. Sorry, but I can't seem to find a way to reproduces the error...

Comment: depends If you don't want to use. But make sue you row value will be fill by your array